# Passing through value on ionic popup but getting MouseEvent instead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to pass through an value on the Ionic popup but keep getting `MouseEvent {isTrusted: false, isIonicTap: true, screenX: 0, screenY: 0, clientX: 97…}` whenever I log
`statementId` to the console. What am I doing wrong?

**View.html**

```
<a class="button button-assertive" ng-controller="PopupController" ng-click="showRequestTakedownPopup(statement.id)"><i class="icon ion-sad"></i></a>
```

**PopupController**

```
function PopupController($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $state) {
    $scope.showRequestTakedownPopup = function() {
        $ionicPopup.confirm({
            title: 'Request Takedown',
            content: 'Would you like to create a takedown request for this item?',
            scope: $scope,
            buttons:[
            {
                text: "Yes",
                type: 'button-positive',
                onTap: function(statementId){
                    console.log(statementId);
                    $state.go('sidemenu.takedown-justification', { "statement": statementId });
                }
            },
            {
                text: "No",
                type: 'button-positive',
                onTap: function(){
                }
            }
            ]
        })
    };
};
```

I have checked and confirmed that `statement.id` is correct in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say that onTap

> will by default close the popup
>   and resolve the popup promise with its return value. If you wish to prevent the
>   default and keep the popup open on button tap, call event.preventDefault() on the
>   passed in tap event.
>   ([source](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/))

so what you want to do is call the popup like you would call a promise

```
   confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
     if(res) {
       console.log('You are sure');
     } else {
       console.log('You are not sure');
     }
   });
```

In your case the following should work:

```
$scope.showRequestTakedownPopup = function(statementId) {
    var myPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
        title: 'Request Takedown',
        content: 'Would you like to create a takedown request for this item?',
        scope: $scope,
        buttons:[
        {
            text: "Yes",
            type: 'button-positive',
            onTap: function(e){
                return statementId; 
            }
        },
        {
            text: "No",
            type: 'button-positive',
            onTap: function(){
            }
        }
        ]
    });
    myPopup.then(function(statementId) {
        console.log(statementId);
        $state.go('sidemenu.takedown-justification', { "statement": statementId });
    });

};
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestions but now `$scope.statementId` returns undefined whenever I log it to the console in `onTap: function(statementId){ ... }` . Any idea why?

Comment: then it is not on the scope. thats why i added a comment. you did not give us code where you set your `statementId`. Where does it comefrom? You might need a function that sets `$scope.statementId` on click or something.

Comment: ah now i see what you are doing. you have an `ng-click` function that passes the statement.id parameter. So you need to alter that `showRequestTakedownPopup` to also accept the parameter. Edited code above